# Problem getting bash to pass variable with spaces as single filename to tar

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

Beating my head against the wall with this one.  I'm using a bash script to read a file of directory names (one name per line no characters escaped) into a variable and use that variable to invoke tar on those directories.  If one of the directories has a space in it I can't get it to be passed to tar correctly (keeps splinting it to two separate items doesn't preserve the escaping I add).  I've tried many variations of this but below is the most current. Really frustrating part is echo shows the command taking the exact form I would expect it to and running that manually works as expected. Thanks in advance for the help.

### bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

#build list of directories to backup from backup_dirs.txt
BACKUP_DIRS=
while read dir; do
    #create escaped version of string to handle spaces, etc...
    esc_line=$(printf '%q' "${dir}")

    echo "###### adding dir '${esc_line}'"

    #add new dire to list
    BACKUP_DIRS=${BACKUP_DIRS}\ "${esc_line}"
done < backup_dirs.txt


echo tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 ${BACKUP_DIRS}

#run backup    
tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 ${BACKUP_DIRS}
```

---

### sample backup_dirs.txt contents

```
my_stuff
My Stuff
```

---

### observed output

```
###### adding dir 'my_stuff'
###### adding dir 'My\ Stuff'
tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 my_stuff My\ Stuff
my_stuff/
tar: My\\: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Stuff: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Just add them to an array instead of trying to squeeze them into a single string

Comment: In this case you can just `tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 -T backup_dirs.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `mapfile` to read `backup_dirs.txt` into a bash-array:

```
    mapfile -t BACKUP_DIRS <backup_dirs.txt
```

and then pass it to `tar` like this:

```
    tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 "${BACKUP_DIRS[@]}"
```

If you have lots of backup directories I'd recommend using command-line option `-T` to specify a text file directly:

```
    tar -cjvPf backup.tar.bz2 -T backup_dirs.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, not surprisingly I made this problem more difficult than it should have been out of ignorance, the -T option was best for my case and also using the -X as well.  A lesson learned there that wasn't obvious from the man pages was the -X option needs to come before the -T, the exclude patterns provide through -X appeared to have no affect otherwise.